# Prisma cause data lost when i run migration

Tags: node.js, database-migration, prisma

I am using prisma with data pipeline. i am fetching data from different database and create new portal with few changes in database. Database can also change in production time, i don't want to lose ant data from data factory. is it possible to run  migration without cause data lost.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `prisma migrate resolve` in order to ignore some migrations before running `prisma migrate deploy`, [here you go more information](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/baselining)